# Implementing Secure Re-Authentication Flow with Time-Based Exemption in Azure B2C Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using Azure B2C custom policy for the login journey in my application.

I need to implement a secure re-authentication flow for certain high-security actions, such as updating personal information or bank details.

This re-authentication flow should prompt the user to provide additional authentication, such as biometric login, before allowing them to proceed with these high-risk actions.

Additionally, once the user has completed the "Step Up Authentication," they should not be required to "Step Up Auth" again within a 30-minute time frame.

Could you please guide me on how to implement this re-authentication flow with time-based exemption in Azure B2C?

Currently, I am redirecting the user to a separate login screen for re-authentication, but I believe there might be a more suitable approach.

Your advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is the ProfileEdit flow.

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/mfa-absolute-timeout-and-ip-change-trigger), where you can see an example of "The user has not done MFA in the last X seconds".

For biometric auth, see [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/fido2).